# how to prevent variables compiling before the import into another partial in sass?

Tags: css, import, sass, partials

This question seems a *bit tricky*, but would, in my case, be a great way to **factorize** my code.

I would like my code to be decline from the partial _global.sass in several themes like page1.sass, page2.sass, and just redefine variables at the beginning of the themes, and not directly in the code. This way, i would just reaffect variables in the beginning of the final sass file, and not change the code every time it need to be change, on every pages.

For that, i think i must find a way to prevent _global.sass from compiling its variables so i can redefine them in the pageX.sass file and finally compile them.

in the partial _variables.sass file

```
$bg-color-page1: black
$bg-color-page2: red
$bg-color-page3: blue
$bg-color-page4: yellow
// etc.
$bg-color-page-global: grey /* you're obliged to affect a value when you declare a variable
```

in the partial _global.sass fil

```
@import variables

body
    background-color: $bg-color-page-global
```

in the final sass files, pageX, or page1.sass for instance

```
@import variables
@import global

$bg-color-page-global: $bg-color-page1

body
    background-color: $bg-color-page-global
```

With this code, the background will be grey on every pages using the pageX.cass file, because the code of _global.sass is compiled before his import in pageX.sass. I want it to adapt, black background for page1.sass, red for page2.sass, etc.

Do you now a way to prevent the compiling of variables before the import of the partial in another sass file ?

Thank you for your precious help.

Answer (score 0):

use sass default key and work with [@use](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use) and [@forward](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/forward), `@import` is deprecated

1. create `style/main.scss`

```css
@use "modules/yourModule";
```

2. create color vars in `style/settings/_settings.scss` with !default

```css
$color1: #000 !default;
$color2: #fff !default;
```

3. overwrite defaults in `style/modules/_yourModule.scss`

```css
@use 'sass:map';
@use '../settings/settings';

// overwrite here
$color1: #ccc;

.yourModule {
  color: $color1;
}
```

hope that helps.